# Seeking QGIS alternative for ArcGIS Schematics

Tags: qgis, schematics

I want to draw a schematic drawing from a network.There is an [extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/schematics) in ArcMap that can do this.

Is there an extension or a way to do this in QGIS?

Comment: You gave a link, but unless you have ArcGIS it's difficult to imagine how it might be used,  Can you add more information about how you were using schematic and your requirements, to allow someone from a non-ArcGIS world to potentially answer the question.    You might also consider posting to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ...I happen to have done some research a few month ago and came up with nothing. I ended up writing a procedure in PostgreSQL/PostGIS PL/Python that suited my needs (nationwide generalized road network, highways and primary roads, into a schematic network)...but I left the code on my former work profile, probably wiped by now. It's a damn shame...anyway, I read [this](http://www.cs.uu.nl/archive/sw/schematic-map/ck-apsn-draft01.pdf) paper and followed their references to get a general idea on where and how to start. Just in case you're willing to have a go at this yourself.

Comment: Any news on that topic?